# Should I use an abstract method or an instance variable for data that should be specified by sub-class?

Tags: java, variables, abstract-class

I am writing an abstract class and I have a variable that should be defined by the sub-class (in this case it is an int which is used in the super-class).  I can't decide whether to define a `protected` variable with a default value and let the sub-class change the value either in the constructor or through a `setter` method.  Or to define an abstract method in the parent class such that all sub-classes must implement it and return the value they want to be used (then access the method in the super-class using the abstract method).  Can anyone tell me if there are any great reasons why one way should be preferred over the other?

Abstract Method:

```
public abstract int getValue();

public int getValue() {
    return 5;
}
```

- Pros:

Forces sub-class to think about this value and choose what they want it to be.

- Cons:

No default value, so even if most of the sub-classes just want to use the same value they still have to implement the method. (The method can be made non-abstract and return the default value, but then you lose the advantage of forcing sub-classes to think about the value)

Protected Variable:

```
protected int value;

public SubClassImpl() {
    value = 5;
}
```

- Pros:

Can define a default value and sub-classes can just ignore it if they don't care.

- Cons:

Authors of the sub-class aren't made aware of the existence of the variable, so they might be surprised by the default behaviour.

Comment: Is the value immutable? If not, who is responsible for changing the value?

Comment: There is no requirement for the value to be immutable but I wouldn't expect it to be changed after creation of the object.

Comment: I think it is better to look at it from the other perspective. If there is no requirement to make it mutable, then start out by making it immutable. Change it to mutable if a requirement appears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it depends...

- Does the value have to be able to change during the lifetime of the object? If not, you might want to make it a protected constructor parameter, and make it a final private variable in your base class.
- Might subclasses have reason to compute the variable based on other mutable state? If so, an abstract getter would be appropriate.
- Otherwise, I'd probably use a private variable and a protected setter. I'm generally not a fan of non-private variables. This could allow you to react to changes in the value in your base class, such as changing other computer fields. To avoid the presence of a default value you could combine this with a constructor parameter to force an initial value which the subclass could change later via the setter.

Comment: Thanks, the protected constructor is probably the way I want to go.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use an abstract method, because that allows you to take advantage of [covariant return types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) but a (mutable) field or property does not.

For example in [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), this allows [ForwardingSortedMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingSortedMap.html) to extend [ForwardingMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html).